# Plot shows different answer for the similar arguments

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've just started to learn mathematica so forgive me if it's a simple question. I'm trying to find out why `Plot` that contains expression with `ReplaceAll` works different from `Plot` with `Set` . I have:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
I0[t_] = HeavisidePi[(t - 1/2 10^-9)/10^-9];
sol = DSolve[{D[I2[t], t]*R == I1[t]/C0, I0[t] == I1[t] + I2[t], 
    I2[0] == 0}, {I1[t], I2[t]}, t];
I2 = I2[t] /. sol[[1]];
Plot[I2 /. {C0 -> 5*10^-12, R -> 500}, {t, -2 10^-9, 10^-8}]
C0 = 5*10^-12;
R = 500;
Plot[I2, {t, -2 10^-9, 10^-8}]
```

For some reason first `Plot` gives the right answer and the second one wrong. I expected same answers. What is the reason for the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's interesting.  If `t` is set first the value at `t = 0.5* 10^-9` is 0.181269 but if it stays symbolic till later the result is 0.402672

```
a = Plot[
   I2 /. {C0 -> 5*10^-12, R -> 500}, {t, -2 10^-9, 10^-8}];

b = Plot[Evaluate[
    I2 /. {C0 -> 5*10^-12, R -> 500}], {t, -2 10^-9, 10^-8}];

x = 0.5* 10^-9;

c = I2 /. t -> x /. {C0 -> 5*10^-12, R -> 500}
```

> 0.181269

```
d = I2 /. {t -> x, C0 -> 5*10^-12, R -> 500}
```

> 0.402672

```
Show[{a, b, ListPlot[{{x, c}, {x, d}}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Same question was posted on [MSE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182890/plot-shows-different-answer-for-the-similar-arguments)